# Django Class-Based Views - Erro de NoReverseMatch

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema CRUD com class-based views.
Tenho um app que as views de List, Create e Delete estão funcionando perfeitamente, porém a Update está com um problema. A partir da ListView, tento fazer o UpdateView de um dos objetos, mas os dados do objeto não são passados para a UpdateView, gerando o erro:

```
NoReverseMatch at /workOrder/8/
Reverse for 'WorkOrderUpdate' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['workOrder/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

workOrderList.html - Aqui os objetos são mostrados corretamente.

```
{% for workOrder in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ workOrder.id }}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="{% url 'WorkOrderUpdate' workOrder.id %}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Editar</button>
      </a>
    </td>
    ~ Botão de delete omitido ~                   
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py - Minhas quatros urls, todas funcionando exceto a Update.

```
path('workOrder/add/', WorkOrderCreate.as_view(), name='WorkOrderCreate'),
path('workOrders', WorkOrderList.as_view(), name='WorkOrderList'),
path('workOrder/<int:pk>/', WorkOrderUpdate.as_view(), name='WorkOrderUpdate'),
path('workOrder/<int:pk>', WorkOrderDelete.as_view(), name='WorkOrderDelete'),
```

workOrderUpdate.html - Aqui meu form que deveria receber o id passado pelo ListView.

```
<form action="{% url 'WorkOrderUpdate' workOrder.id %}" method='post'>
{% csrf_token %}
```

Se eu alterar para `{% url 'WorkOrderUpdate' 8 %}`, o formulário é exibido perfeitamente (8 é um dos id presentes na minha tabela).

views.py - Exatamente como as views dos outros apps que estão funcionando (estruturalmente falando).

```
class WorkOrderUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = WorkOrder
    form_class = WorkOrderForm
    template_name = 'workOrders/workOrderUpdate.html'
    success_url = '/workOrders'
```

forms.py - Exatamente como os forms dos outros apps que estão funcionando (estruturalmente falando).

```
class WorkOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        fields = ['customer', 'status']


    customer = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label="Selecione", queryset=Customer.objects.all())
    createdAt = forms.DateField(label="Criado em", input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    status = forms.CharField(label="Status")
```

Tenho dois outros apps extremamente semelhantes a esse, e eles estão com todas as views funcionando corretamente.
Alguém teria alguma ideia do porque minha id não é passada pra UpdateView?

Comment: Olá, Denis. O problema é que provavelmente o `workOrder.id` está retornando None. Poderia compartilhar a sua view por gentileza? @Denis Callau

Comment: Adicionado views.py e forms.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione o objeto atualmente sendo editado ao contexto com o nome desejado. Adicione esse método na sua classe que herda de `UpdateView`.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['workOrder'] = self.object
    return context
```

Comment: Funcionou! Mas agora porque nesse app eu precisei desse método e nos outros dois não? São todos iguais, só mudam o models praticamente.

Comment: É difícil dizer ao certo sem testar as outras apps, mas o nome do objeto é definido em uma propriedade chamada `context_object_name`, da classe [SingleObjectMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin).@Denis Callau.